# Equation for making a circle in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d, parametric, spherical-coordinates

I have a 3D space with axis $(x, y ,z)$ and I can make a circle in the $xy$-plane.

To make a circle in the xy-plane I currently use spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ where $r =  1$, $\theta = \pi/2$, and $\phi = [0, 2\pi]$ and this is converted to Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ using the equations:

$x = r\sin\theta$ $\cos\phi$

$y = r\sin\theta$ $\sin\phi$

$z = r\sin\theta$

**How do I tile this circle around the `y-axis`** ? so it can circle on any plane starting from the `xy-plane` to the `zy-plane`. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Do you require your result to be in spherical coordinates again? Because giving a result in cartesian coordinates would be rather easy.

Comment: @MvG cartesian coordinates is exactly what I need. I'm only using spherical coordinates because it made the equation easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rotate your setup: let $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$ parametrize your circle like you did, but use $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ to describe the rotation of your plane. Then you can use

\begin{align*}
x &= r\cos\phi\cos\theta \\
y &= r\sin\phi \\
z &= r\cos\phi\sin\theta
\end{align*}

For $\theta=0$ this gives a circle in the $xy$ plane, and for $\theta=\frac\pi2$ the circle lies in the $zy$ plane.

Comment: This solution fits like a glove. Thanks.